# Is there a collection of designed CD/DVD labels, Wallpapers, or similar Ubuntu related artwork?

Tags: graphics, 13.10, artwork

Is there a collection of designed CD/DVD labels, Wallpapers, or similar Ubuntu related artwork? I would like to label my disks "Ubuntu Server 13.10 x64" but I cant seem to find disk artwork. Thanks

Comment: The current DIY Marketing Page lacks any form of cd artwork for anything beyond 12.10. Might need to keep searching for artwork for 13.04 & 13.10.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [DIY Marketing](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DIYMarketing) page.  The page contains downloadable resources to create your own Ubuntu marketing and conference material.<sup>[DIYMarketing](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DIYMarketing)</sup>